# Loading a new JSP Page based on user selection from select list

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

thanks in advance for your help, hopefully just a quick question here.

I am looking to link to another page based on the selection a user makes from a select list.

For example, if the user should select "Injection" from the list he will be forwared onto the "Injection" JSP page as soon as he clicks it. Is there any sort of jsp equivalent of .getSelectedIndex in JSP? Just started so I don't know that much about it.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <%@include file ="headerJSP.jsp" %>

    <center>
    Please select an OWASP topic:
    <select id="OWASPTopicList">
        <option value="" selected>Choose a topic</option>
        <option value="injectionJSP.jsp">Injection</option>
        <option value="https://www.google.ie/">Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)</option>
        <option value="TopicThree">Broken Authentication and Session Management</option>
        <option value="TopicFour">Insecure Direct Object References</option>
        <option value="TopicFive">Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)</option>
        <option value="TopicSix">Security Misconfiguration</option>
        <option value="TopicSeven">Insecure Cryptographic Storage</option>
        <option value="TopicEight">Failure to Restrict URL Access</option>
        <option value="TopicNine">Insufficient Transport Layer Protection</option>
        <option value="TopicTen">Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards</option>
    </select>
    </center>

    <script>
        $(function(){
        // bind change event to select
        $('#OWASPTopicList').bind('change', function () {
        var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
        if (url) // require a URL
              { 
              window.location = url; // redirect
              }
        return false;
         });
       });
   </script>

    <%@ include file="footerJSP.jsp" %>
```

EDIT: Thanks for the help, used the code suggested but it is not working. Edited my code to reflect its current state, any ideas whats wrong? Page compiles and runs fine, but selecting "Injection" or "Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)" does not redirect as desired (these are my two test options, main goal is for all options to redirect to other jsp pages).

EDIT 2: Perfect Hadrik, working grand now, thanks very much :D

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will need javascript to add that behavior to a select option event.

Comment: Why don't you want to submit the form and make forwarding / redirection afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `js` for `jQuery` in your code. Here I have `jquery.min.js` under `js` directory under my `webapps`.So, It goes like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then bind `id` of `select` to `onchange` event using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
           $('#OWASPTopicList').bind('change', function () {
             var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
             alert(url); // This will help to check whether JS is getting executed.
             if (url) { // require a URL
                window.location = url; // redirect
             }
             return false;
           });
       });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#dynamic_select').bind('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```